# How to change the font size of the scientific format axis label in subplots?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, axis-labels

I'm plotting two histograms in a single figure using subplot command. I want to change the font size of the scientific notation in the axis label. I can change the size by using  `ax.xaxis.get_offset_text().set_fontsize(14)` in a single plot. But in the subplots, this command is not working.

Here is my code for the 2 subplots.

```
plt.figure()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.subplot(1,2,1)      
num_bins = 30
# the histogram of the data
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(time0, num_bins,  density = True, edgecolor='black', 
histtype='bar',facecolor='red', label = '$M_1=1000$')
plt.legend()
plt.title('A', fontsize = 16)
plt.ylabel(r'P($\tau_s$)', fontsize=16)
plt.legend(fontsize=5)
plt.xticks(fontsize=14)
plt.yticks(fontsize=14) 
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='both', scilimits=(0,0),fontsize=20, fontweight = 
'bold',useMathText=True, useLocale = True, loc = 'best')
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=True)
plt.ticklabel_format(fontsize=20)
ax.yaxis.get_offset_text().set_fontsize(14)
ax.xaxis.get_offset_text().set_fontsize(14)

plt.subplot(1,2,2)      
num_bins = 30
# the histogram of the data
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(time1, num_bins,  density = True, 
   edgecolor='black', histtype='bar',facecolor='red', label = 
   '$M_1=10000$')
plt.legend()
plt.title('B', fontsize = 16)
plt.legend(fontsize=5)
plt.xticks(fontsize=14)
plt.yticks(fontsize=14) 
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='both', scilimits=
(0,0),fontsize=20, fontweight = 'bold',
    useMathText=True, useLocale = True, loc = 'best')
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=True)
plt.ticklabel_format(fontsize=20)
ax.yaxis.get_offset_text().set_fontsize(14)
ax.xaxis.get_offset_text().set_fontsize(14)

tight_layout()
plt.savefig('dist.eps')
```

Please help me if you know the solution.

Comment: You shouldn't be mixing `plt.subplots` and `plt.subplot` in the same code.  Leave out `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` and do `ax = plt.subplot(1,2,1)`. Then you can use `ax` as the axis for the subplot you're working on.

Comment: @JohanC thanks a lot. This format "plt.gca().yaxis.offset_text().set_fontsize(16)." worked for me. Also, thanks for pointing out the mistake.